# Effect does not trigger properly

Tags: angular, typescript, signals

I am working on an implementation of conways game of life in angular (v17.1.0) with typescript and the gameMap signal from the service seems to be updating but the update method does not fire. I am completely lost on this one.

map.component.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, effect } from '@angular/core';
import { GameService } from '../../_shared/services/game.service';
import { GolMap } from '../../_shared/models/golmap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrl: './map.component.scss',
})
export class MapComponent {
  @ViewChild('gridCanvasElement')
  gridCanvasElement?: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
  @ViewChild('cellsCanvasElement')
  cellsCanvasElement?: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  private cellsCanvas?: HTMLCanvasElement;
  private cellsCtx?: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  private gridCanvas?: HTMLCanvasElement;
  private gridCtx?: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  gameMap?: GolMap; //the map element in question

  private zoom = 20; 
  private camera = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  private dragging = { left: false, right: false, lastX: 0, lastY: 0 };

  private resizeListener: (() => void) | undefined;

  constructor(private gameService: GameService) {
    effect(() => {
      this.updateMap(this.gameService.gameMap());
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.cellsCanvas = this.cellsCanvasElement?.nativeElement;
    this.cellsCtx = this.cellsCanvas?.getContext(
      '2d'
    ) as CanvasRenderingContext2D;

    this.gridCanvas = this.gridCanvasElement?.nativeElement;
    this.gridCtx = this.gridCanvas?.getContext(
      '2d'
    ) as CanvasRenderingContext2D;

    if (this.gridCtx) {
      this.resizeCanvas();
      this.resizeListener = () => this.resizeCanvas();
      window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeListener);

      this.initializeGameCells();
    }
    this.gridCanvas?.addEventListener(
      'click',
      this.handleCanvasClick.bind(this)
    );
    this.gridCanvas?.addEventListener('wheel', this.handleZoom.bind(this));
    this.gridCanvas?.addEventListener('mousedown', this.startDrag.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.endDrag.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.drag.bind(this));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.resizeListener &&
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeListener);
  }

  private updateMap(map: GolMap): void {
    console.log('Updating Map');
    this.gameMap = map;
    this.drawCells();
  }

  private handleCanvasClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (!this.gridCanvas) {
      console.error('Grid Canvas not initialized');
      return;
    }
    const rect = this.gridCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const clickX = event.clientX - rect.left;
    const clickY = event.clientY - rect.top;

    // Calculate the cell coordinates
    const cellX = Math.floor(clickX / this.zoom + this.camera.x);
    const cellY = Math.floor(clickY / this.zoom + this.camera.y);

    // Check if a cell exists at these coordinates
    const existingCell = this.gameMap?.cells.find(
      (cell) => cell.x === cellX && cell.y === cellY
    );

    if (existingCell) {
      this.gameService.removeCell(cellX, cellY);
    } else {
      this.gameService.createCell(cellX, cellY);
    }
    this.drawCells();
    this.drawGrid();
  }

  private startDrag(event: MouseEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.dragging.left = event.button === 0;
    this.dragging.right = event.button === 2;
    this.dragging.lastX = event.clientX;
    this.dragging.lastY = event.clientY;
  }

  private drag(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (!this.dragging.left && !this.dragging.right) {
      return;
    }

    const deltaX = event.clientX - this.dragging.lastX;
    const deltaY = event.clientY - this.dragging.lastY;

    if (this.dragging.right) {
      this.camera.x -= deltaX / this.zoom;
      this.camera.y -= deltaY / this.zoom;
    }

    this.dragging.lastX = event.clientX;
    this.dragging.lastY = event.clientY;

    if (this.dragging.left) {

      if (!this.gridCanvas) {
        console.error('Grid Canvas not initialized');
        return;
      }
      const rect = this.gridCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      const mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
      const mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

      const cellX = Math.floor(mouseX / this.zoom + this.camera.x);
      const cellY = Math.floor(mouseY / this.zoom + this.camera.y);

      const existingCell = this.gameMap?.cells.find(
        (cell) => cell.x === cellX && cell.y === cellY
      );

      if (existingCell) {
        this.gameService.removeCell(cellX, cellY);
      } else if (!existingCell) {
        this.gameService.createCell(cellX, cellY);
      }
    }

    this.drawGrid();
    this.drawCells();
  }

  private endDrag(): void {
    this.dragging.left = false;
    this.dragging.right = false;
  }

  private handleZoom(event: WheelEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    if (!this.gridCanvas) {
      console.error('Grid Canvas not initialized');
      return;
    }

    const zoomIntensity = 0.1;
    const oldZoom = this.zoom;
    const delta = event.deltaY > 0 ? -1 : 1;
    this.zoom *= 1 + delta * zoomIntensity;

    const canvas = this.gridCanvas;
    if (!canvas) {
      console.error('Grid Canvas not initialized');
      return;
    }

    const rect = this.gridCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const mouseX = (event.clientX - rect.left) / oldZoom;
    const mouseY = (event.clientY - rect.top) / oldZoom;

    this.camera.x += mouseX - (mouseX * oldZoom) / this.zoom;
    this.camera.y += mouseY - (mouseY * oldZoom) / this.zoom;

    this.drawGrid();
    this.drawCells();
  }

  private resizeCanvas(): void {
    this.setCanvasSize(this.cellsCanvas as HTMLCanvasElement);
    this.setCanvasSize(this.gridCanvas as HTMLCanvasElement);

    this.drawGrid();
    this.drawCells();
  }

  private setCanvasSize(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement): void {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }

  private initializeGameCells(): void {
    this.gameService.createCell(0, 0);
    this.gameService.createCell(1, 0);
    this.gameService.createCell(2, 0);
    this.gameService.createCell(0, 1);
    this.gameService.createCell(1, 2);
  }

  private drawCells(): void {
    console.log('Drawing Cells');
    const canvas = this.cellsCanvas;
    const ctx = this.cellsCtx;

    if (!canvas || !ctx) {
      console.error('Cells Canvas or Context not initialized');
      return;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    this.gameMap?.cells.forEach((cell) => {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.fillRect(
        (cell.x - this.camera.x) * this.zoom,
        (cell.y - this.camera.y) * this.zoom,
        this.zoom,
        this.zoom
      );
    });
  }

  private drawGrid(): void {
    const canvas = this.gridCanvas;
    const ctx = this.gridCtx;

    if (!canvas || !ctx) {
      console.error('Grid Canvas or Context not initialized');
      return;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'grey';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

    let effectiveCellSize = this.zoom;
    let cellsPerGridCell = 1;

    while (effectiveCellSize < 5) {
      effectiveCellSize *= 4;
      cellsPerGridCell *= 4;
    }

    // Calculate the adjusted camera position based on the effective cell size
    const adjustedCameraX = this.camera.x / cellsPerGridCell;
    const adjustedCameraY = this.camera.y / cellsPerGridCell;

    // Calculate the start points for grid lines
    const startX = -(adjustedCameraX % 1) * effectiveCellSize;
    const startY = -(adjustedCameraY % 1) * effectiveCellSize;

    ctx.beginPath();
    for (let x = startX; x <= canvas.width; x += effectiveCellSize) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
    }
    for (let y = startY; y <= canvas.height; y += effectiveCellSize) {
      ctx.moveTo(0, y);
      ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

game.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { GolMap } from '../models/golmap';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GameService {
  public gameMap = signal<GolMap>(new GolMap());

  constructor() {}

  getCell(x: number, y: number) {
    return this.gameMap().getCell(x, y);
  }

  performStep() {
    this.gameMap.update((map) => {
      map.step();
      return map;
    });
  }

  createCell(x: number, y: number) {
    this.gameMap.update((map) => {
      map.createCell(x, y);
      return map;
    });
  }

  removeCell(x: number, y: number) {
    this.gameMap.update((map) => {
      const cell = map.getCell(x, y);
      if (cell) {
        map.removeCell(cell);
      }
      return map;
    });
  }

  clearMap() {
    this.gameMap.update((map) => {
      map.cells = [];
      return map;
    });
  }
}
```

I tried to debug to locate the problem and in the service the performStep() method works perfectly (I logged the map before and after and it changed in the correct manner).
So the problem has to be somewhere in the effect but everywhere else the effect seems to be working properly (creating/removing a cell works and updates the map then draws the cells). Only when performing a step the map seems to be updating but drawCells just wont be executed (also anything else i put into the updateMap method.

Update:
I did some more testing and it seems that the signal.update function only updates if the object reference changes. So if I create a new GolMap and deepcopy the older golmap onto it the change detection works. I dont understand why they would make this feature in the first place tho when the change detection cannot even detect property changes inside an object.

Comment: is `map.step()` a mutator or accesor function?

Comment: @oksd 
it directly changes the cells and generation variables from the GolMap class:

  step() {
    this.cells = this.calcNextCellsGeneration();
    this.generation++;
  }

i did some more testing and it seems that the signal.update function only updates if the object reference changes. So if i create a new GolMap and deepcopy the older golmap onto it the change detection works. I dont understand why they would make this feature in the first place tho when the change detection cannot even detect property changes inside an object.

Comment: [See code comment](https://angular.dev/guide/signals#signal-equality-functions) Yes, unfortunately the object reference must change otherwise Angular does not recognize the difference and therefore does not trigger change detection

Comment: Wasnt mutate there for exactly those cases?

Comment: [This function has been removed](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/9ea54d47f50e2c6028fe9a70ff734fd455f75660)